Is it Possible in TypeScript to Disable the Rule Behind TS(1345)
TypeScript will throw an error ("An expression of type 'void' cannot be tested for truthiness.ts(1345)") with valid debugging code like:
const getFooPlusTwo = (foo) => console.log(foo) || foo + 2;

There are various hacks to work around that (adding +, ,, etc.) but they don't work in all circumstances ... and more importantly, they're unnecessary work for no benefit (JS works perfectly fine without them).
Most TypeScript rules can be turned off.  Is there any TypeScript (or ESLint) rule that I can disable to make TypeScript not throw these errors?

That’s not very readable. Why what are you trying to do?

I'm trying to debug. The original version of the function looked like this:const getFooPlusTwo = (foo) => foo + 2;.  I used a (very common) debugging pattern by adding the console.log(foo) ||  to determine what the value of the foo argument is.  Of course, it doesn't look beautiful, but it's not supposed: it's debugging code.

You can augment global Console to replace void with undefined there - this sounds more ergonomic than comma operator with parens. declare global { interface Console { log(msg: any, ...args: any[]): undefined; } }

That sounds like an answer! Unfortunately I saw Josh's answer first, but if you can provide this as answer I'll happily upvote it, and change my accepted answer (if SO will let me).

You can augment global console object to make its methods return undefined instead of void. It's safe since console.log really returns undefined unconditionally. Just this (you can add other console methods here as well):
declare global { 
   interface Console { 
      log(msg: any, ...args: any[]): undefined; 
   } 
}

const getFooPlusTwo = (foo: string) => console.log(foo) || foo + 2;

Playground Link (read this to understand declare global, you likely need that, but not in playground).
This won't allow generally using void in such boolean chains, and that's probably good: if you accept a callback returning void, you can accidentally use it in callback() || 'something' and be disappointed when that callback returns 1.
function test(callback: () => void) {
    return callback() || 'something'
}
test(() => 1)

"An expression of type 'void' cannot be tested for truthiness" is the only error typescript raises for the snippet above, so disabling it may really accept a broken code.

You won't be able to disable this typescript rule, console.log returns void and you can't use a void expression in a truthiness check.
An alternative option would be to use the comma operator to split the log and return the value. The comma operator evaluates each of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the last operand.
export const getFooPlusTwo = (foo: number) => (console.log(foo), foo + 2);


That's unfortunate: the comma doesn't work in many cases (and again, developers should have at least have the option of ignoring errors that TypeScript creates out of nothing).  But thanks for the answer!
